# Problem trying to use position absolute in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for my english.

I made a web component, kind of List View, and there is a button at its right. It shows only a item, when you click it, it grows and shows all the items:

[image]

The problem is, with `display: inline-block` when I click in the List View, it grows and pushes down the items below.

[image]

I tried to use `display: absolute` and bigger z-index when I click, but obviously this happens:

[image]

The button on the right moves left below the List View. While it is what i want:

[image]

Maybe it can be done putting a fixed location with JS, but, there is a easier way to do this with css?

### **Edit:**

The buttons are inside a div, in this example called a-div.

[image]

This is the simplified code:

```
<div class="a-div">

    <list-view style="display: inline-block;"class="wButton">
    </list-view>

    <button class="arrow-button" type="button">
       <img src="images/arrow-right.svg" alt="">
    </button>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a-div{
  width: 50%;
 display: flex;
}
.a-div > *{
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

I could use a flex-end on the arrow button, but it will look like this:

[image]

`a-div`and `b-div` both are inside of another div.

**And something important, the with of the List View is dynamic.**

Hope you can help me, thanks on advance!

Comment: I'd probably make the `div` container absolute and use flex on the list and button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply `position: absolute` to your list it goes outsite the flow so the button with the arrow is placed right under it. Add a `margin-left` to the button equal to the width of list (plus a little bit more)

Comment: That's a good solution, I could generate a dynamic margin-left with JS depending on the actual with of the List View, but i thought maybe there was a solution using only CSS. Thanks!